# Can you compost paper towels?

Tags: compost

Can newspaper and paper towels be composted? I ask because I am hoping to set up a composting system at my work place and we use a lot of paper towels. 
I have heard the bleach/chemicals in the ink or the process of making the paper towels can be harmful to some soils etc.

Comment: Both paper towels and newspaper are carbon rich (see also [this post](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1262/99)), so you'll need to add a lot of nitrogen sources to keep a proper C:N ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes to both, with conditions. You should not try to compost any paper towels that have synthetic additives, including bleach, and are advertised as disinfectants or fragrant etc. The best paper towels to compost are those made of 100% recycled material.

Newsprint is actually sterile enough, it can be used to transport evidence if there is no other good way to do so. Newspaper, cut into thin strips are actually a good way to start a compost pile.

Do you know where you heard of problems with newspaper and paper towels? It would be interesting to see what the concerns are.

Here is a Cornell University link that addresses newspaper composting:

http://compost.css.cornell.edu/faq.html

Comment: Thanks. So with the paper towels, the regular white ones are fine? My work place uses hundreds a day and we just buy the white normal ones. They are not fragrant or anything fancy at all. Or would I need to make sure they are the ones made without using any bleach etc?

Comment: Check with the manufacturer if they are bleached. 100% post-consumed material is the best, like the kind Seventh Generation (for example) puts out. White paper towels will contain bleach typically and in large quantities will be bad for your compost pile. Large quantities of bleached paper towels, if ungreased, are best recycled.

Comment: To be clear, I edited my answer, discussing bleach in paper towels explicitly.

Comment: I got super confused when I heard from several composting companies where I live about their opinions on this. One company that composts says no to paper towels and one company says yes.

Comment: I assume the company that is not ready to take paper towels does not have the capacity to separate out the undesirable paper towels and thus refuses to accept it. We see this with recycling programs. Sorting is a big part of the process and is very expensive, so many recycle programs severely limit what they will accept.

Comment: I would also assume that a potential problem with paper towels, beyond how any brand is manufactured, is that they are often used to mop up or to wipe on different chemical solutions.  I think you'd have to be careful in defining when one goes into compost (just drying hands after washing and rinsing) or trash (used one with window cleaning solution).

Comment: Yes, agreed. It is important only to dispose of the ones that have not been used on chemicals.

Comment: Interesting question RDub!  Living in an RV for years I learned to never ever put anything other than toilet paper made to dissolve for RV's.  Definitely no paper towels.  They did not differentiate between 'recycled' and Brawny for instance.  Even regular toilet paper is tough to compost.  I just wouldn't use anything commercially made in compost.  You should ask if any of your composting companies compost human poo and sawdust?  Where is it that you live?  Gosh, if they do this, you are very lucky. Do you have landscaping, gardens?  I'd just give all that paper to these composting companies.